# How to access a variable from one function in another

Tags: python, function

I know this may seem as a copy as many other questions asked on stack overflow, but honestly i didn't understand any of those questions. I just need someone to clarify this for me, and please don't flag this. I'm currently running on python 3.4.2, windows 8.1

Sample code:

```
def function_A():
    my_Name = "Pamal Mangat"
    return my_Name

def function_B(name):
    print("Hello " + name)

function_B(function_A.my_Name)
```

Answer (score 4):

You need to call `function_A()` the way you're calling `function_B()`; that's how you get the return value. You can't access variables inside a function like that; besides, they only exist while the function is running.

```
def function_A():
    my_Name = "Pamal Mangat"
    return my_Name

def function_B(name):
    print("Hello " + name)

function_B(function_A())
```

Comment: @PamalMangat, there are alternatives.. but this is the right solution given your code.